# Mobile menu scroll disables/enables only once

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, menu, overflow

https://jonathanrace77.github.io/

Ok, so I have my mobile menu set to disable the page scrolling once it's activated by changing the body, overflow-y to hidden / scroll:

```
let lockScroll = () => {
  if ($("body").css("overflow-y", 'scroll')) {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    console.log("locking");
  } else {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    console.log("unlocking");
  }
};
```

```
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  background: #000002;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This works perfectly up to a point:

1. I load the page and can scroll (good)
2. I hit the menu button and can't scroll (good)
3. I hit the exit menu button and can scroll again (good)
4. I hit the menu button again and can still scroll (bad)

I can't think for the life of me why this is happening. I'm using Scss, is there any way that it could be messing things up somehow?

edit:
This is the JS that triggers lockscroll()

```
//Mobile menu clicked
function mobileMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navcontents");
  lockScroll();
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.display = "block";
    $("#navbar").animate({ left: "0vw" }, 300);
    $("#navcontents").css("opacity", "1");
    $("#navbar").css("opacity", "1");
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
    $("#navbar").animate({ left: "100vw" }, 300);
    $("body").css({ position: "static", overflow: "auto" });
  }
```

It is triggered by this:

```
  <div id="mobilemenubutton">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="mobileMenu()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the function/event listener that calls 'lockScroll'?

Comment: Updated! I added the trigger from the HTML too

Comment: Does clicking the exit menu button change the body's CSS?

Comment: Doh! That was interfering with it. After revising it I found I didn't even need to make a call to that lock function, I could do it all from the mobile menu function. Thanks! :)